# Adding more delay to animation removing background

Tags: jquery, animation

It's a simple question I create a simple animation to add a green background color to a Div and then removing, what I want it's to make the transition from green to without the color more smoother maybe adding more delay to the transition but, even adding a bigger delay the animation show us the same.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ganador').empty().css('background-color', '#74DF00').append("prueba").animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFF' }, '60000000000');
});​
```

[My Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7VDq/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove quotes around delay http://jsfiddle.net/g7VDq/3/